# How do I Configure Search To Remove Test-Dev Users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I would like to know how to configure search to remove Test Dev users in Author Refinement web part. I am using SharePoint Online.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People search basically pulls the data from User Profile Service.there are couple of ways to do it.

1. If you dont want those user at all in the SharePoint then configure the exclusion filters in UPA sync then UPA will not import those users.
2. I think you can create the Seach Rule but not sure.
3. create a custom user profile property and then mapping it to a managed property in search.  Then, using the managed property, we are able to exclude unwanted profiles from being included in the People search scope.

[Exclude Unwanted Users from People Search](https://ryansteeno.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/exclude-unwanted-users-from-people-search/)